# Delphi Using unit procedure on form

Tags: delphi, procedure

I'm learning OOP and I have created a basic program so far. I have create my own clas:

```
Type
Zombie = class
  private
   fLife : Integer;
   fAge : Integer;
   fHeight: String;
  public
   Constructor Create(pLife, pAge : Integer; pHeight : String);
   Procedure SetLife(pLife : Integer);
   function GetLife : Integer;
   Procedure ShowLife;
end;
```

The procedure ShowLife does exactly what it says:

```
procedure Zombie.ShowLife;
begin
ShowMessage(inttostr(fLife));
end;
```

I'm trying to call this procedure on a Form but it says undeclared identifier:

```
procedure Tform1.ShowLifebtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Zombies_Unit.ShowLife;
end;
```

I have included the unit in the user of the Form. How can I use methods on another form

Comment: You need to call the method `ShowLife` on an **object** (i.e. a class instance) of type `Zombie`, **not on a unit**. The unit is just the file in which the class `Zombie` is defined. The answer by @ZdravkoDanev shows how to do this. Units can also define so-called global functions, but these are not methods of a class like `Zombie`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create and free the object before/after you use it. The pattern is like this:

```
MyZombie := TZombie.Create(10, 20, 30); 
try
  MyZombie.ShowLife(); 
finally
  MyZombie.Free();
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of your class and call the method of that object like

```
MyZombie := Zombie.create(20,15);
MyZombie.ShowLife;
...
MyZombie.free;
```

Sending from mobile, cannot format code.

EDIT/SUPPLEMENT:

As my short answer seems to be suitable to tech bad habits (I am sorry for that) I want to add the following advices to the asker:

Please use Try/Finally constructs to avoid that objects are not removed in case of an error occuring between create() and free() like Zdravko Danev's answer points out. It also makes sense to use common naming conventions to make your code easier to understand (e.g. TZombie as class name).

Comment: You are missing a try finally

Comment: Correct, i think this was a beginners question an I intended to poinr him into the correct direction on usung objects.

Comment: @MichaSchumann if it's a beginner question, all the more reason ***not*** to teach ***bad habits***.

Comment: That's correct, as I said, I wanted to point in the right direction. Omg.

Comment: @MichaSchumann I think you're missing the point. You're demonstrating bad resource protection; i.e. you're pointing in completely the ***wrong direction***.

Comment: If this is really the point, I better no longer answer any questions as these answers will always lack some of the so important patterns.

Comment: Many times you will create an object and only free it at a later point in time when no longer required. For testing/learning purposes, one often declares a variable as a member of the Form class, and then creates the object in the OnCreate event handler, and destroys it (call Free) in the OnDestroy event handler. That way you can test the object for the lifetime of the Form.

Answer (score 3):

You must pay attention in one thing: Your class is in the same file of your form? If the answer is no, you must declare the unit name on `uses` of your form file like:

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MyForm: TMyForm;

implementation

uses unitzombie; //The name unit where is your class

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

After solving this little problem, you must create your object before calling this methods:

```
procedure Tform1.ShowLifebtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
   Zombi: Zombie; 
begin
      Zombi := Zombie.Create(5,10,15);
   try
      Zombi.ShowLife;
   finally
      Zombi.Free;
   end;
end;
```